# Open website in background without displaying with App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm going to write my first Android app. For this I'd like to use **App Inventor** as it seems the easiest way to get started.

In this app i have several buttons and every button should open a specific predefined HTTP address in the background and nothing else.

e.g.:

```
Button pressed → open http://bla.com/myinput in background → exit
```

Is this possible?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @TomerShemesh Thanks, but with AppInventor this doen't work as i undersood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `webviewer` component and set its visiblility to `false`. Then together with the `Webviewer.GoToUrl` block open the webpage in the background. Later if you want to display one of the webpages, just set the visibility of the webviewer to `true`.

Btw. it helps to [do the tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor, see also the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php).

Comment: Thanks (especially for the links!)